# ShowCaseView display for many activites

Tags: android, showcaseview

i am using ShowCaseView  in activity A and B and singleShot(1) but problem is if i visit to activity A it showing but now if i visit B it not showing so i think it is having only one state any way we can set as per activity

Comment: i am using activity  any way ?

Comment: So you have to configure it in 2nd activity.

Comment: ya i have defined and any way i can remove store share pref ?so that if i want to show it when user click on button